# Maven Clean doesn't clean the old class and generate new class

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am having strange issue in Maven. After doing Maven clean install, when I opened the jar file by 7 zip, inside the jar file, I can see two class files instead of one, which are an old class file and a newly compiled class file with current timestamp as per attached image.

I have tried troubleshooting such as clearing the target folder and trying to recompile, fixing a known issue of Maven compiler 3.1 (useIncrementalCompilation -yes (true)).

However it is still the same and I ran out of ideas. I am also new to Java and it's quite important to me. Any kind of help and idea from you is highly appreciated.

Trans

[Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7h4R.png)

POM

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Some Content here</groupId>
  <artifactId>alert</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
   
 <dependency>
  <groupId>Some Content Here</groupId>
  <artifactId>processing</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.6</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>sax</groupId>
     <artifactId>sax</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
     <version>3.6</version>
 </dependency>
  
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.5</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
     <version>6.0</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory> 
  <resources>
   <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
     </resources>
     <plugins>
   <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Log

```html
[INFO] javax/transaction/UserTransaction.class already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/javax.javaee.api/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/javax.javaee.api/javaee.api-compact/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/javax.javaee.api/javaee.api-compact/pom.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/javax.javaee.api/javaee.api-compact/pom.properties already added, skipping
[INFO] DBConnect.properties already added, skipping
[INFO] EmailSetting.properties already added, skipping
[INFO] SourceConnect.properties already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ alert ---
[INFO] Installing C:\AA\alert\target\alert-1.jar to C:\Users\AA\.m2\repository\com\bb\automation\alert\1\alert-1.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\AA\alert\pom.xml to C:\Users\AA\.m2\repository\com\bb\automation\alert\1\alert-1.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\AA\alert\target\alert-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar to C:\Users\AA\.m2\repository\com\bb\automation\alert\1\alert-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.371 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-13T10:47:07+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/404M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Effective POM

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Some Content Here</groupId>
  <artifactId>alert</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>Some Content Here</groupId>
      <artifactId>processing</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sax</groupId>
      <artifactId>sax</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\AA\alert\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\AA\alert\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\AA\alert\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\AA\alert\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\AA\alert\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\AA\alert\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\AA\alert\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\AA\alert\target</directory>
    <finalName>alert-1</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\AA\alert\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\AA\alert\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\AA\alert\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\AA\alert\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you defining the source directory and the resources? These are the default so don't do it...furthermore have you done the `mvn clean` on plain command line?

Comment: i cloned the project from git and accidentally did it. Now i have removed it and did mvn clean from cmd... Still the same though. Thanks for your reply anyway :)

Comment: Is one of your classes which does not want to go away stored in your local maven repository (`~/.m2/repository`) as a result of some earlier build? ... or is this class part of your current project's source?

Comment: Please add the full log output of `mvn clean` here...

Comment: i am not sure it's what you meant. but here u go!! i have tried in new workspace too as i think class file is corrupted. still not working though https://snag.gy/jwCLJK.jpg

Comment: I actually use that alert jar file as dependencies to other web project, i got  java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file 
 errpr .  https://snag.gy/GrKmZR.jpg

Comment: @diginoise Hey... the class which doesn't want to go away was in local repo as external jar, then i got source code and did deployed again. That's the reason why it happened if i am not mistaken. Anyway, after purging local repo dependencies, it's the one that got away now :) haha. Thanks for your reply !!

Comment: @TransSiberian nice one! An **UP** on my suggestion [and a credit in your answer ;)  ] would not go amiss.

Comment: @diginoise First of all, i am from different time zone, sorry for late reply Secondly, My idea to purge comes from a guy who advised me from other community. He advised me to remove the .m2 repo. however as i don't want to delete repo, i used that plugin to resolve dependencies. I don't mind to give **up vote** to you, but when it comes to idea / suggestion credit, that guy will be rightful owner. Please refer the screenshot. https://snag.gy/FcdBqz.jpg

Comment: I voted up for your as per your request @diginoise

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue by Purging local repository dependencies of the project. As per plugin documentation,

*The default behaviour of the plugin is to first resolve the entire dependency tree, then delete the contents from the local repository, and then re-resolve the dependencies from the remote repository.*

It's working well now!! Cheers!!

https://snag.gy/qvzoAL.jpg

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html

```html
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

Credit:

A guy from other community called Martijn advised me to remove .m2 repo, but as i am afraid to delete .m2 repo, instead i used that plugin to remove dependencies from local repo of the project after reading multiple online resources.

https://snag.gy/FcdBqz.jpg